# Skewing menu item with css, unskewing the text it's not working

Tags: html, css, layout, sass

I already checked every other question about the argument, I tried the various solutions, but if I apply them they don't work, the skew is not happening. It's a menu, I applied the `display: block` on the links, if I unskew it just doesnt stay skewed.

The structure:

```
     <div class="container">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item active">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">Link Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

The css (SCSS)

```
 ul.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;

  li.menu-item {
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
    transform: skewX(-15deg);

    a {
      display: block;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: $white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding: 17px 15px 13px 30px;
      transform: skewX(15deg);
    } // a
  } //.menu-item
```

I know it should work, based on the other snippets in other answers, but something is wrong and I can't quite figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be working as expected [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/poEpBKz).

Comment: It seems to be working fine (ie the background menu-item blue is skewed and the text is upright). Perhaps you could put up a snippet which shows the problem because what you have posted doesn't seem to given @LouysPatriceBessette useful pen.

Comment: @AHaworth https://codepen.io/K3nzie/pen/XWjVwbM I might be just really dense, but it doesn't work.. that's my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply the `padding` and the color on the `a` which is taking all the `.menu-item` space and even more because it overflows.

In the inspector, select the `menu-item`... You should notice it IS skewed:

[image]

Here is the relevant part of this [*CodePen*](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/xxEpNEp?editors=0100) where I fixed the thing:

```
li.menu-item {
  margin-right: 4px;
  position: relative;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
  
  /* Put that here! */ 
  padding: 17px 15px 13px 30px;
  background: $lightRed;
  &:hover {
    background: $redActive;
  } // &:hover
  
  a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: $white;
    font-family: "Cinzel", serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    // padding: 17px 15px 13px 30px;
    // background: $lightRed;
    transform: skewX(15deg);
    transition: all 0.3s;
    text-decoration: none;
    // &:hover {
    //   background: $redActive;
    // } // &:hover
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that in the inspector.